# Normal Brakes? Master Cylinder replacement gone bad?

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor, brake-calipers, brake-booster, disk-brakes

The brakes after I bled them and changed the master cylinder feel like they start to grab when the pedal is 1/3-1/2 the way depressed, is this normal? I did bench bleed the master cylinder before I installed.

Comment: It depends? What's the year/make/model of the vehicle? What was it like before the changes? Have you ever driven a car like the one you did the work on? If so, how did that feel? Lots of variables and not much info to go on here ;-)

Comment: 1995 Acura legend sinking pedal was the problem beforehand. Never driven another like mine!